# Perl loop between two arrays

Tags: perl, loops

```
@a1 = qw(1 2 3) 
@a2 = qw(1 2 3 4 5)
```

looking have the resultant of a calculation between a1 and a2 be inserted as the value of a2[0]. example would be 1+1 = 2  going into a2[0] as 2, then the next calculation would be 2+2 (a2[0] + a1[1]) resulting in a2[0] = 4, then 4+3 (a2[0]+a1[2]) resulting in a2[0] = 7, then move on to the next line in a2 and perform the same function against a1.

when all said and done the result would be from `print @a2;`

7 8 9 10 11

Comment: so where are you facing the problem in implementing this ?? What's the exact problem you wanted to be address here?

Comment: I've tried `my $a2 = map { my $a = $_; map { $_ + $a } @a1 } @a2;` as a nested map but it does not work. I've tired foreach loops but there I can not break the boundry of having to list each item from @a1
`foreach (@2) {$_ = $a1[0] + $_;$_ = $a1[1] + $_;$_ = $a1[2] + $_;
          }`

Comment: not homework, special project for a class, no credit, just something i want to do to understand. Not even a perl class, it's linux and the teacher ran out of stuff to teach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you're adding the total of the values in the first array to each element in the second array.

```
my $total = 0;
($total += $_) for @a1;
($_ += $total) for @a2;
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple and I was overthinking it way too much. Thank you and this is now solved.

Answer (score 2):

Using relevant list functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util      qw( sum   );
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );

my @a1 = qw( 1 2 3     );
my @a2 = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 );

my $sum = sum(@a1);

@a2 = apply { $_ += $sum } @a2;
```

Refer:

- [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util)
- [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils)

Also refer [*Fergal*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242639/perl-loop-between-two-arrays/4242826#4242826), which is simpler in this case.